# Display Driver stopped responding and recovered successfully- Blue Screen - HP Elite Book

Tags: drivers, display, crash, hp-elitebook

I have HP ELiteBook , this problem has become a routine headache for me (after every 20, 25 minutes_ - While using, suddenly everything hangs and black out goes around and then a message pop at the task bar below that display driver stopped ...and successfully recovered but the hangs and black screen continues and then the Blue Death Screen comes" and then i have no other option but to restart

Is this a driver problem ? Hardware problem ? what should I do  Please be specific , no stories and theories

Comment: Please include more details, such as the model of the laptop, OS installed, driver version, and the message on the blue screen.  The last is really important & often may indicate where the problem lies.  i.e. IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL is very different from BAD_POOL_CALLER.  And, if the system runs hot, have you got it on a cooling pad?

Answer (score 0):

It's a driver issue that crops up with windows 8. Not all NVIDIA drivers work that well with the Elitebook/Nvidia video cards. You can either roll back to the drivers on the HP site, or experiment to find ones that work well with whatever version of windows you're on.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really old now, but in case you're still having this problem - I was getting BSOD errors on my HP 2730p very frequently whenever it was not docked.  After months of trying to figure it out, I found that the Location Service drivers were corrupt.

Try disabling & uninstalling the Location Services.

From Control Panel:

1. Access Location Settings and uncheck `Turn on the Windows Location platform` (for Win8, it's a similar option in Win7), then click OK
2. Access Device Manager and click the drop-down menu for View and tick "Show Hidden Devices" and select Devices by Type.
3. Scroll down the Devices list and click the arrow to the left of "Sensors". This should now list the Windows Location Provider.
4. Right-click on Windows Location Provider and select Uninstall then click OK

Start up the laptop un-docked using battery power, and if you don't get the BSOD within 30 minutes of using it then that's it.